# Google sheet: Error on copy sheet to other spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to copy a sheet into other spreadsheet by using this code. However, there is error:
[Exception: Specified sheet must be part of the spreadsheet]

```
function copy_to_A() {
  
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Bestwise_id);
 var tempsheet = source.getSheetByName('Bestwise-tocopy');

 destination.insertSheet('New Sheet Name', 0, {template: tempsheet});
}
```

Comment: On what line is the exception occuring? There is a lot of context missing here.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, it seems that when the Spreadsheet of the source sheet is different from the destination Spreadsheet, `insertSheet` cannot be used for other Spreadsheet. It seems that this is the current specification. So when you want to use `destination.insertSheet('New Sheet Name', 0, {template: tempsheet});`, how about the following workaround? The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Copy `tempsheet` sheet from source Spreadsheet to destination Spreadsheet.
2. Using `insertSheet('New Sheet Name', 0, {template: tempsheet})`, the copied sheet is used.
3. Delete the copied sheet.

When this flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function copy_to_A() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Bestwise_id);
  var tempsheet = source.getSheetByName('Bestwise-tocopy');
  
  // 1. Copy `tempsheet` sheet from source Spreadsheet to destination Spreadsheet.
  var copiedSheet = tempsheet.copyTo(destination);
  
  // 2. Using `insertSheet('New Sheet Name', 0, {template: tempsheet})`, the copied sheet is used.
  destination.insertSheet('New Sheet Name', 0, { template: copiedSheet });
  
  // 3. Delete the copied sheet.
  destination.deleteSheet(copiedSheet);
}
```

#### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer,Object))
- [deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet)